# How to Import Json file to Neo4j

Tags: python, json, import, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a Very big Json file and I would like to import it to Neo4j but When I used Apoc I get this error

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.json`: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (String)"[[{ "; line: 1, column: 1]
```

The code I am using to import the file is:

```
CALL apoc.import.json("file:///eight9.json")
```

The Start of the file looks like this:

```
[[{ 
    "id" : "149715690143449899009",
    "objectType" : "activity",
    "actor" : {
```

But when I checked online it is a valid Json File.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining about "[[{ ".  Below is taken from neo4j documentation; https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/import/load-json/. A json format file starts with { so your json is NOT accepted by neo4j;

```
For example:
{
 "name":"Michael",
 "age": 41,
 "children": ["Selina","Rana","Selma"]
}
```

Please remove [[ at the start and ]] at the end of your file then try it again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, After removing the above said I got this error:

'Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.json`: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 2]'

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: You json file does not have a close } at the end. Copy and paste your data into this and you will see the problme:  https://jsoneditoronline.org/.  The website can also do "AUTO Repair" for you.